# How to use i18next to load resource from PHP?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have the following PHP script to load resource for i18next translation

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM translations';
...
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($translations);
?>
```

But how can I use it with my react js app? Originally, I load the translations with json that is in client-sided, as was done in the i18next official tutorial.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import translations from './translations.json';

const resources = translations;

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({ resources, lng: 'zh', keySeparator: false, interpolation: { escapeValue: false } });
```

I want to load using PHP on the server side. But the following won't work:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import xhr from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import axios from 'axios';

function loadCurrent(url, options, callback, data) {
    axios.get(url).then((res) => {
       callback(res.data, { status: res.status });
    });
}

const i18nextOpt = {
 backend: {
     loadPath: 'http://localhost/translation.php',
     parse: function(data) { return JSON.parse(data); },
     ajax: loadCurrent
 },  
 getAsync: false
 };

 i18n.use(xhr).init(i18nextOpt);
```

What should I change in my React script? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use fetch? Why do you need i18next-xhr-backend and axios?

Comment: The above is my first tries. I am not very familiar with it. It seems that they won't accept non-json file.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not really familiar with i18next either. I imagined sth like: `fetch("XXX.php").then((res)=>(res.json())).then((data)=>{i18next.init({resources: data})}`, but that might be totally off.

Answer (score 2):

the trick is:

adding resources with import you had some structure like:

```
{ lng: { ns: { key: value } } }
```

on xhr every lng-namespace pair is loaded individual...so file must be

```
{ key: value }
```

but in lng / ns requested -> therefore loadpath is something like:

```
http://localhost/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.php
```

https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations

no need for axios just use the xhr-backend

Comment: So I have to rename my PHP script in my server?